# Implicit function the right approach

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Given $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$
what is $y’_x$?

I’ve gone back and forth on this and I thought I could perhaps use the implicit function theorem, but then again is there a need to? I have the answer options but can’t seem to get to them so I must be doing something wrong. Not sure if it’s from the algebra or my approach.

Comment: What does the notation "$y_x'$" mean?

Comment: The derivative of y with respect to x.

Comment: Please show us what you did, or we can't tell you your mistake.

Comment: Odd notation. Usually “$y’$” or “$y_x$”, or classically “$dy/dx$”. Never seen that notation before. It almost looks like a second derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ${x^2 \over a^2}+ {y^2 \over b^2} = 1$, hence
$y = \pm b  \sqrt{1-{x^2 \over a^2}}$.

We can define two functions
$y_-(x)  = - b  \sqrt{1-{x^2 \over a^2}}$,
$y_+(x)  =  b  \sqrt{1-{x^2 \over a^2}}$ defined on $[-a,a]$ and
differentiable on $(a,-a)$, with

$y_-'(x) = {xb \over a^2} {1 \over \sqrt{1-{x^2 \over a^2}}} = -{b^2 \over a^2} {x \over y_-(x)}$,
$y_+'(x) = -{xb \over a^2} {1 \over \sqrt{1-{x^2 \over a^2}}} = = -{b^2 \over a^2} {x \over y_+(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I've said this before in other answers, but we can encapsulate our relation as a two variable function
$$F(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
It is true for any two variable function that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u}$$
In the special case that $u=x$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
Applying this to our example,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x,y)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1)=0= \frac{2x}{a^2}+\frac{2y}{b^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{-x}{y}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Surely $(x^2)’ =2x$, $(1)’=0$, and for $(y^2)’$ use the chain rule.

It may help to think of $y$ as a function $y(x)$, so that term becomes $([y(x)]^2)’$.